# Deserialize Json with varying dictionary size in unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, rest

I am using newtonsoft.json in unity and trying to deserialize from an api endpoint.

I have my Json response set up kind of like this..

```
{}pattern_order
   {}LB
   {}LC

Actual end point:
{"key":"value","pattern_order":{"LB":{"A":[{"order":["A","G","X","D"],"style":"SK"},{"order":["D","X","D"],"style":"SK"}],"B":[{"order":["A","D","X","G","C"],"style":"SK"},{"order":["C","X","D"],"style":"SK"},{"order":["D","G","X"],"style":"AT"}]},"LC":{"A":[{"order":["A","D","X","G","C"],"style":"AT"},{"order":["C","X","D"],"style":"SK"}],"B":[{"order":["A","D","X","G","C"],"style":"AT"},{"order":["C","X","D"],"style":"SK"}]}}}
```

Here, LB and LC have a similar structure, but I want to add more objects inside pattern_order.
What is the best way to deserialize such a json in unity?

Comment: This is no valid JSON .. could you add an actual JSON structure? In general [Json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com) usually provides a good starting point

Comment: I have edited my question, really sorry for before.. I thought it would be easier to understand that way

Comment: What you posted is still not valid JSON ... you have e.g. some `.` where there should be `{` I guess

Comment: I made an edit and checked again.. works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the `.` that shouldn't be there as mentioned I just have put it into [Json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) which results in

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
public class A
{
    public List<string> order { get; set; }
    public string style { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<string> order { get; set; }
    public string style { get; set; }
}

public class LB
{
    public List<A> A { get; set; }
    public List<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class LC
{
    public List<A> A { get; set; }
    public List<B> B { get; set; }
}

public class PatternOrder
{
    public LB LB { get; set; }
    public LC LC { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public List<string> levels { get; set; }
    public PatternOrder pattern_order { get; set; }
}
```

From there it is actually a simple step:

```
public class Thingy
{
    public List<string> order;
    public string style;
}

public class Root
{
    public string key;
    public List<string> levels;

    // HERE YOU GO!
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Thingy[]>> pattern_order;
}
```

and

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

You can rename `Thingy` (and all other classes) to whatever you want ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have to brush up a bit on dictionaries
Really sorry for not editing properly before, I am relatively new and still quite don't get the hang of it

Comment: @charanvendra see the updated solution: I think you generalize it even more using a second nested Dictionary so also `A` and `B` could have more additional options

Comment: Awesome exactly what I had confusion about